# Regex to match ids in a css file?

Tags: regex

With the following input:

```
#element{ color: #333; }
#element2,
.element3,
.whatever{ background: red; }

.test,
.test2, .test3,
#test111,
.element5555, #fooooooter{ display: none; }

#element8 tr .bacon{ font-size: 10000em; }
```

How do I use regex to match these:

```
#element  
#element2  
#element8
#test111
```

And not match these:

```
#333
```

I tried more variations so far and I can't come up with anything useful.

This is what I tried the latest:

```
(#).*[{]
```

But it seems to skip some selectors.

Comment: This is non-trivial for a few reasons. There's a lot of ambiguity between words and color identifiers. The following are all valid colors: `#abc`, `#beefee`, `#a12`, `#beef12`. Differentiating those from IDs won't be 100% perfect. You could ignore text between `{` braces `}`, but they can span multiple lines. You might be able to throw a `:` into the mix and get something good enough for your needs, but a perfect multi-line regex is non-trivial. Be wary of any simple-looking answers below, if you need something perfect.

Comment: How come nobody has posted [the Chtulhu link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) yet? Don't use regex to parse structured information.

Comment: @tripleee all people answered this, don't like to parse these kind of dirty strings with regex patterns but they like to use their minds figuring out how to solve new problems come to mind, and also regex, apart from it's meaning (*regular expression*), is more than dirty to be used for just dirty things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=[^}]*\{)`

It explicitly matches valid characters in CSS selector. [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

http://regexr.com?36e6v

Don't forget to remove comments and quotation like `content: '{}'` before applying this regex.
Matching comments and quotations is possible with regex. Remove it using unrolling skill, separately.
(I think unrolling is complicated and inefficient enough to rule the integration out.)

It does match color if `{}` blocks are nested as are in Sass, less

Comment: If you do need parse structured text, RegExp shall be the last resort you turn to, though.

Answer (score 0):

OK,Check out this one,it exactly matches what you need;

```
^\#[a-z]+[0-9]* //(Multiline = true)
```

If you need to capture **ID Name**,use this;

```
^\#(?<IDName>[a-z]+[0-9]*)  //(Multiline = true)
```

This regex has a capture group named **IDName** which gives you *name of the ID*.

Demo [here](http://regexr.com?36e4q).

Comment: Sry, I don't want "element", I want "any ID". Fixed the question.

Comment: If the color is something like `#aaa`, this will match.

Comment: @Kalley Well,see if it matches *#aaa* or *#fooooooter* now,check out the demo.

Comment: http://regexr.com?36e59

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it (http://regexr.com?36e5i):

`#[^{,;]*(?:[{,\n])` will also match ids followed by other selectors (eg., `#element8 tr .bacon`)

`#[^ {,;]*(?:[ {,\n])` will only match ids only (so you'd get the `#element8` part from the example above, but not the rest)

Comment: Almost: http://regexr.com?36e4t

Comment: Updated, with a couple options based on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this /#[^1-9]+/g

```
var t=" #element ";
var p=t.search(/#[^1-9]+/g);
alert(p);
```

or /#[^1-9.@#$%^&*()!]+/g  if want to remove more symbols other then numbers

Answer (score 0):

***Upadated based on a comment***

This will work for you:

```
/(?![^{]+})(#\S+)\b/g
```

Check it here: http://regex101.com/r/rF9iR9

Comment: Naughty `linear-gradient` will break this... http://regex101.com/r/bP2bN3

Comment: Yet Another CSS3 problem from box-shadow... http://regex101.com/r/pX9kY1

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme and Yet Another Update.

Comment: But sadly... `box-shadow` accepts multiple values.  `box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff inset, 0 0 1px #000;`

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme it seems like a nightmare. how about newly pattern?

Comment: That's fine :) ... hold on, did we forget comments and quotations? (I think it's time for me to give up since stackoverflow is complaining about extended discussions...)

Comment: It catch `#nightmare:hover` too.