# Using regex replace CSS ID or class by PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following CSS code:

```
#np-toolbar-l a{ position: relative; padding: 0px 8px; line-height: 30px; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; }
#np-toolbar-l a:hover{ background-color: #EFEFEF; opacity: 0.7; }
#np-toolbar-l a *:hover{ cursor: pointer; }


/** Icon */
#np-toolbar [class^="icon-"]{ font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 5px; }
```

I am trying to replace `np-toolbar` to another ID,

I just want to match `np-toolbar` **not** `np-toolbar-l` or something like this,

here's a tutoral about how to capture all the IDs from CSS:

```
#-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=[^}]*\{)
```

*source: [Regex to match ids in a css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938390/regex-to-match-ids-in-a-css-file)*

I couldn't find out how do I search a "compelete ID" by regex,

here's my example: (It'll still count `np-toolbar-l` in)

```
/(?<=(#|\.))(np-toolbar)+(?=( |:||\[))/
```

**EDIT**: ummm, jsut added some symbols behind it,

it looks like the answer which I am looking for

```
/(?<=(#|\.))(np-toolbar)+(?=( |:|\[|\{|\.|,))/
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gM6hS5/1 Though IIRC, this won't work for all id allowed by HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a specific ID, you can greatly simplify your regex:

```
/(#np-toolbar)(?=[{.,\s])/g
```

That should find the ID wherever it appears in the CSS. It first matches the ID exactly, then only allows `{` (for beginning the style), `,` (for listing selectors), `.` (for appended classes), or space/tab/newline characters afterwards, preventing it from matching IDs like `np-toolbar-1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this regexp:

```
/#np-toolbar(?![-\w])/
```

which means: match all "#np-toolbar" inclusions if inclusion doesn't end with "-" or any \w symbol